# "IndexMissingException[[jdbc] missing]", "status" : 404

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

i want to index and search mysql database using elastic search & I followed this tutorial

[elasticsearch-river-jdbc](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/Quickstart)

At first i downloaded elastic search and installed river-jdbc in its plugin folder. 
then added mysql-jdbc inside ES_HOME/elasticsearch-0.90.1/plugins/river-jdbc/
Then started elasticsearch and Started another terminal window, 
and created a new JDBC river with name my_jdbc_river with this curl command

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bablool",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "babloo",
        "sql" : "select * from details"
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "jdbc",
        "type" : "jdbc"
    }
}'
```

then when I run this command: `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/jdbc/jdbc/_search?pretty&q=*'`

and im getting following error:

```
"error": "IndexMissingException[[jdbc] missing]", "status" : 404
```

plz help me....

Comment: Please provide some code, what have you tried so far?
Generally **404** error means that the file is missing/the path is incorrect

Comment: Did you include the jdbc connecter (mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar) from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/#downloads

Comment: Same error here.
@vignesh I've just followed https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/tree/1.3 installation guide. I launch mysql query to a local mysql server.
@Atav32 I used mysql-connector-java-5.0.8 and I put in `plugins/jdbc/` folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm bumped into the same error following the tutorial mentioned in the question... after reading again the documentation, I noticed that I forgot to restart the ES after install the river_jdbc plugin.

This [tutorial](http://blog.comperiosearch.com/blog/2014/01/30/elasticsearch-indexing-sql-databases-the-easy-way/) is also interesting if you starting to learn about indexing SQL databases.